Definite integral involving exponential and logarith function
Working with Dilogarimth function, we get the following definite integral
$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{t^2\,\ln^{n}(t)}{(1-e^{x\,t})(1-e^{y\,t})}\,dt$$
with $n=1,2,3,...$ and $x,y>0$.
I wonder if is possible write in terms of elementary functions or (more probably) in terms of special function.
Any help is welcomed.
Edit: I have added $t^2$ at numerator, in order to convergence.

The integral $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{t^{\alpha}}{(1-e^{x,t})(1-e^{y,t})},dt$ is equal to $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\Gamma(1+\alpha)}{\left((n+1)x+(k+1)y\right)^{1+\alpha}} $$ If this has a closed form then differentiate it $n$ times and set $\alpha=0$ to get the desired result.

The integral does not seem to converge since it blows up near $t=0$

Yes, it's true. I forgot a "t" at the numerator.

Still does not converge. Try looking at the series expansion near $t=0$.

Assuming $n=1,x=1,y=2$, following the approach suggested by @Zima, differentiating the summation once and setting $\alpha = 2$, I get the numerically evaluated sum to be $-0.340481$ which matches with the numerically evaluated integral.
